# QT compile Error undefined reference to `qt_version_tag@Qt_5.7'

Tags: qt, qt5.7

I'm using a shared library in my project and when I try to compile my project in Qt I experienced error like this undefined reference to `qt_version_tag@Qt_5.7' related with shared lib so file. How can I fix it. I'm using use Qt version 5.6.1. Operating system Ubuntu, I compiled lib myself with qt 5.7. I experienced this error while ı'm trying to compile my project in qt 5.6.1.

Comment: Some little information will be not so useless, like: which operating system, which compiler, pre-built libraries or built by yourself, chaintool and so on..